# AndroidViewAnimations doesn't animate properly in onCreate

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-animation

I'm trying to use the awesome library [AndroidViewAnimations](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations).

I have two animations, one that is animated when you press a button, and one when the activity starts.

When you press the button the animations behaves like it should, but the animation that is executed in the onCreate method behaves odd.

```
public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    //This happens when you start the activity
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(1000).playOn(findViewById(R.id.hello_world));

    }

    //This happens when you click the button
    public void animate(View view) {
    YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(1000).playOn(findViewById(R.id.hello_world));
    }
```

The animation that is executed in the onCreate method seems to animate from the top-left corner while the animation that is executed when you press the button animates from the center. The latter is the correct behavior.

onCreate: Animation animates from the top-left corner. - Not correct

Button: Animations animates from the center. - Correct

Anyone knows what may cause the strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by implementing the onWindowFocusChanged method:

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(1000).playOn(findViewById(R.id.hello_world));
        }
    }
```